# ggplot2: legend and bar plot order are not matching

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is enough data to reproduce the problem:

```
    structure(list(sensorheight = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yrmonth = structure(c(1459468800, 
1459468800, 1459468800, 1459468800, 1459468800, 1459468800, 1459468800, 
1459468800, 1459468800, 1459468800, 1462060800, 1462060800, 1462060800, 
1462060800, 1462060800, 1462060800, 1462060800, 1462060800, 1462060800, 
1462060800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    SummIndex = structure(c(23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
    29L, 30L, 31L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
    31L), .Label = c("Non-vented", "Outside", "Long", "Open", 
    "Open Shaded", "Outside Main", "Outside Secondary", "Shaded", 
    "Unshaded", "AB Outside", "AB Shaded", "CD HT", "CD Mid-T", 
    "CD Outside HT", "CD Outside Mid-T", "EF East 3", "EF Spring Inside 1", 
    "EF Spring Inside 2", "EF Spring Outside", "EF West 3", "EF Winter Inside", 
    "EF Winter Outside", "VKH East", "VKH Outside", "VKH West", 
    "VKSc", "VKSc Outside", "VKSV", "VKSV Outside", "VKY ", "VKY Outside"
    ), class = "factor"), N = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), TempC = c(37.5240740740741, 
    26.8324074074074, 26.8324074074074, 33.8166666666667, 46.5069444444444, 
    27.8731481481481, 49.3949074074074, 28.2796296296296, 47.3606481481481, 
    28.0898148148148, 36.8436379928315, 30.4063620071685, 30.4063620071685, 
    34.8875448028674, 53.7643369175627, 30.7871863799283, 47.6971326164875, 
    30.9341397849462, 39.9758064516129, 30.3969534050179), sd = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), se = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ci = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), freq = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), count = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), CountIndex = c("VKH East 1", 
    "VKH Outside 1", "VKH Outside 2", "VKH West 1", "VKSc 1", 
    "VKSc Outside 1", "VKSV 1", "VKSV Outside 1", "VKY 1", "VKY Outside 1", 
    "VKH East 1", "VKH Outside 1", "VKH Outside 2", "VKH West 1", 
    "VKSc 1", "VKSc Outside 1", "VKSV 1", "VKSV Outside 1", "VKY 1", 
    "VKY Outside 1"), GraphIndex = structure(c(27L, 28L, 29L, 
    30L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 36L, 33L, 34L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
    32L, 35L, 36L, 33L, 34L), .Label = c("Farm 1 HT", "Farm 1 HT", 
    "Farm 1 Mid-T", "Farm 1 Mid-T", "Farm 2 Non-vented", "Farm 2 Non-vented", 
    "Farm 3 Caterpillar", "Farm 3 Open", "Farm 3 Shaded", "Farm 3 Unshaded", 
    "Farm 3 Open Shaded", "Farm 3 Open", "Farm 3 Shaded", "Farm 3 Unshaded", 
    "Farm 3 Caterpillar", "Farm 3 Open Shaded", "AB Shaded", 
    "AB Shaded", "Farm 4 East 3", "Farm 4 Spring Inside 1", "Farm 4 Gothic", 
    "Farm 4 Spring Outside 1", "Farm 4 Gothic", "Farm 4 West 3", 
    "Farm 4 Gothic", "Farm 4 Gothic", "School 1 Caterpillar", 
    "School 1 Caterpillar", "School 1 Standard", "School 1 Standard", 
    "School 2 Standard", "School 2 Standard", "School 4 Standard", 
    "School 4 Standard", "School 3 Standard", "School 3 Standard"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("sensorheight", "yrmonth", 
"SummIndex", "N", "TempC", "sd", "se", "ci", "freq", "count", 
"CountIndex", "GraphIndex"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = c("sensorheight", "yrmonth", 
"SummIndex"), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0L, 1:2, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11:12, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L), group_sizes = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
    sensorheight = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), yrmonth = structure(c(1459468800, 
    1459468800, 1459468800, 1459468800, 1459468800, 1459468800, 
    1459468800, 1459468800, 1459468800, 1462060800, 1462060800, 
    1462060800, 1462060800, 1462060800, 1462060800, 1462060800, 
    1462060800, 1462060800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    SummIndex = structure(c(23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
    30L, 31L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L), .Label = c("Non-vented", 
    "Outside", "Long", "Open", "Open Shaded", "Outside Main", 
    "Outside Secondary", "Shaded", "Unshaded", "AB Outside", 
    "AB Shaded", "CD HT", "CD Mid-T", "CD Outside HT", "CD Outside Mid-T", 
    "EF East 3", "EF Spring Inside 1", "EF Spring Inside 2", 
    "EF Spring Outside", "EF West 3", "EF Winter Inside", "EF Winter Outside", 
    "VKH East", "VKH Outside", "VKH West", "VKSc", "VKSc Outside", 
    "VKSV", "VKSV Outside", "VKY ", "VKY Outside"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("sensorheight", 
"yrmonth", "SummIndex"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame", vars = c("sensorheight", 
"yrmonth", "SummIndex"), drop = TRUE))
#####################################################

month_names <- c("2016-04-01" = "Apr 2016", "2016-05-01" = "May 2016", "2016-06-01" = "Jun 2016", "2016-07-01" = "Jul 2016",
                 "2016-08-01" = "Aug 2016", "2016-09-01" = "Sep 2016", "2016-10-01" = "Oct 2016", "2016-11-01" = "Nov 2016",
                 "2016-12-01" = "Dec 2016", "2017-01-01" = "Jan 2017", "2017-02-01" = "Feb 2017", "2017-03-01" = "Mar 2017",
                 "2017-04-01" = "Apr 2017")

school_colors <- c("VKH East" = "purple2", "VKH Outside" = "grey48",   
               "VKH West" = "sienna3", "VKSc" = "dodgerblue",               
               "VKSc Outside" = "grey48", "VKSV" = "green4",        
               "VKSV Outside" = "grey48", "VKY" = "darkgoldenrod2",
               "VKY Outside" = "grey48")
```

The order of the bars on the graphs and the plot in the do not match. I would like them to match I think something is going on in the factors, but I have been unable to figure it out.

Here is my plot code:

```
ggplot(subset(df, sensorheight %in% c("1") & 
                GraphIndex %in% c("School 1 Caterpillar",
                                  "School 1 Standard",
                                  "School 2 Standard",
                                  "School 3 Standard",
                                  "School 4 Standard")),
       aes(x=GraphIndex, y=TempC, fill=SummIndex, color = SummIndex)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "identity",alpha = 0.5, size = 0) +
  geom_point(shape=21, stroke=0, size = 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "", expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = " ", breaks = c("VKH East", "VKH West", "VKSc",              
                                            "VKSV", "VKY", "VKY Outside"), 
                     values = school_colors, labels = c("School 1 Caterpillar", "School 1 Standard", "School 2 Standard",              
                                                        "School 3 Standard", "School 4 Standard", "Outside")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = " ", breaks = c("VKH East", "VKH West", "VKSc",              
                                           "VKSV", "VKY", "VKY Outside"), 
                    values = school_colors, labels = c("School 1 Caterpillar", "School 1 Standard", "School 2 Standard",              
                                                       "School 3 Standard", "School 4 Standard", "Outside")) +
  facet_grid(.~yrmonth, labeller = as_labeller(month_names), switch = 'x') +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "black", size = 1), legend.text= element_text(size = 11), 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20), axis.text.x =element_blank(),  axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y =element_text(size = 11), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13, margin = margin(r = 10)),
        plot.margin = unit(c(.5,.2,.2,.5), "cm"), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

Here is what I am getting:
[image]
I would like school 3 to be yellow and school 4 to be green. And the orders in the plot and legend to match.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: regarding `school 3` to be yellow, in your `scale_color_manual(...), scale_fill_manual(...)` in `ggplot(...)`, `VKSV` refers to **School3**, and in `school_colors`, _VKSV_ corresponds to `green4`, jst change this to `yellow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df$GraphIndex <- as.character(df$GraphIndex)
```

Plot and legend order now matches.